# Creating Automated Reports in R with User Input

Tags: r, knitr

I have an extensive R script that ranks stocks across 3 indices. I was able to automate it to run for each index and generate a Knitr HTML doc. I have 1 case where the script returns a value (using SVDialogs) and takes in an excel document to finish running. When I add in this case it complicates things since I can't run SVDialogs in RMarkdown.

Any tips on how to overcome this and take in user input while generating an HTML output?

```
indices <- c("TSX", "TSX Small Cap", "S&P 500")
latestdate <- as.Date('2019-01-17')
renderReport <- function(index, latestdate) {
  rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",
                    output_file = paste0(index," Score",".html"),
                    params=list(index=index,
                                latestdate=latestdate),
                    output_options = list(self_contained = FALSE, lib_dir = "libs"))

}
purrr::walk2(indices,latestdate, renderReport)
```

Comment: does the user know which excel document to input before the execution? if not you might want to move that decision point outside the markdown file and pass it as a parameter

Comment: It would have to go in the body of the script since the output returns a list I then have to go run elsewhere to generate the Excel doc which I then paste the path back into the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had to redesign my code to be run from the script instead of markdown then use rmarkdown::render() to create the file. This still allows for user input.